# How to know if a reaction forms H3O+ ions or OH- ions?

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism, equilibrium, solutions

How would you know when an acid or base is paired with $\ce{H2O}$ that it will form an $\ce{OH-}$ ion or a $\ce{H3O+}$ ion? I just started the acid and base equilibrium unit, and I'm just confused on what conditions $\ce{OH-}$ or $\ce{H3O+}$ ions form.

Comment: Why, that's simple: acids give H3O+, bases give OH-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acids are hydrogen ion donors.  When the react with water, they can give a hydrogen ion to form $ \ce{H3O+}$.
For example:

$ \ce{HCl(aq) + H2O(l) \rightarrow  Cl-(aq) + H3O+(aq)}$

Simple acids, such as $ \ce{HCl}$ or $\ce{H2SO4}$, can be recognized as acids by the H at the start of the formula.  Other more complex acids may be written with $ \ce{COOH}$ at the end of the formula, which denotes a carboxylic acid.  An example of this is acetic acid: $\ce{CH3COOH}$.  Otherwise, the name of the compound should give it away.

Bases are hydrogen ion acceptors, and generate $\ce{OH-}$ when they react with water.  Strong bases are generally soluble metal hydroxides, such as $\ce{NaOH}$.  You should be able to recognize them from their formulas.

Simple weak bases often contain nitrogen, like ammonia: $\ce{NH3}$.

$\ce{NH3(aq) + H2O(l) \rightleftharpoons NH4+(aq) + OH-(aq) }$

Answer (score 1):

H3O+ is just the combination of a a $\ce{H+}$ ion, which we know to be released from the dissociation of an acid in an aqueous solution, with a water molecule. It happens because the $\ce{H+}$ is so, so positive (and therefore so reactive) that the water molecules, with its lone pairs (which are locally negatively charged), are willing to form a dative covalent bond with the $\ce{H+}$ ion.

So like Ivan said, whenever you see an acid in an aqueous solution you can consider $\ce{H+ \equiv H3O+}$. The key there though, is that it must be in aqueous solution so that it can dissociate (and the $\ce{H3O+}$ form in the first place). That is the condition that is needed to form it. This is the same for $\ce{OH-}$, which requires an aqueous solution to form and thus release the ions in say NaOH, forming $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$.